# Optimizing Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I would like to optimize the dependencies in the following pom.xml maven file. 
Currently I keep getting warning for duplicate as follows, and it takes forever to build :

```
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransport.class
```

I have tried using m2eclipse to find dependency conflicts and exclude them, however, I wonder if there is a faster way to do this. There are way too many conflicts listed. Practically 80% of the jar files are conflicting. Isn't there a smarter way in maven to include dependencies? If not is ant or any other system smarted?

The following is the pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
            <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <groupId>org.necla.ngla</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>spark-streaming</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark Streaming dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- Log4j api dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- Log4j core dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20131018</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>args4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>args4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>offline</groupId>
            <artifactId>offline</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0-m1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.9.1</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: Dependencies are only downloaded once. This shouldn't be affecting build speed (except once).

Comment: Well I see them being downloaded each time. I guess then one of the questions should also be how can I avoid them being downloaded again and again? I looked and tried mvn clean install -o, but the compile process still takes too long.

Comment: Run it `mvn -X`; and the compile phase happens after the dependencies have been downloaded.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your suggestion? mvn -X does a debug run doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Those `WARNING` messages are from the packaging of the `maven-shade-plugin`, not compilation.  They occur when the plugin tries to combine multiple jars which contain the same classes.

There's no magic bullet in any build tool for resolving class definition conflicts.  If you're pulling in multiple jars into your project that define the same class, you have to find the jars that contain the class, [figure out how](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) those jars are getting pulled into your build, and either change your dependencies or use [exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions) to prevent the problematic jars from being included.

A head start for you: you have one Kafka lib based on Scala 2.9.1 while others are using 2.10.  Using multiple versions of a language within the same project is going to cause problems, shade plugin or not.